# How to compare matrix dimensions?

Tags: r

I'm writing a function here to take 2 matrices as an input and add them. If the shape of the matrices match, then I want to add them. For some reason, its just giving the first element of the resultant matrix. Can someone help me why this happening?

```
mat1<-matrix(50:54, nrow=2, ncol=2)
mat2<-matrix(2:5, nrow=2, ncol=2)
mat_sum<-function(arg1, arg2){
  ifelse(all.equal(dim(arg1),dim(arg2)), arg1+arg2, "not possible")
}
mat_sum(mat1, mat2)
```

Comment: By shape of matrices match you mean they have same number of row & col?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
# identical function is more appropriate 
mat_sum<-function(arg1, arg2){
  if(identical(dim(arg1),dim(arg2))) {arg1+arg2}
  else {print("not possible")}
}
mat_sum(mat1, mat2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   52   56
[2,]   54   58

mat3 <- matrix(1:6, byrow = TRUE)
mat3

mat_sum(mat1, mat3)
[1] "not possible"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `tryCatch` in `mat_sum`, e.g.,

```
mat_sum <- function(arg1, arg2) {
  tryCatch(
    arg1 + arg2,
    error = function(e) message("not possible")
  )
}
```